# ajaxt weird error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this javascript:

```
function updatePage() {   
if (request.readyState == 4)
    if (request.status == 200)
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        update_select($('select[name=island_name]'), data);
    else if (request.status == 404)
        alert("Request url does not exist");
    else
        alert("Error: status code is " + request.status);
}
```

But I keep getting a`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if` error which halts my script. Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't python, indentation doesn't define a block. Use `{` and `}` to group your `if`

Comment: You mean "Unexpected token `else`", didn't you?

Comment: @JuicyScripter No, because since there are no braces on the opening `if()`, the first encountered `else` will be assumed to be associated with it, rather than what the OP intended. Braces save lives!

Comment: @Michael Just try this snippet in js-console ;)

Comment: Ha that was it! Too much Python and not enough js recently. However, now my script runs but I get an `Error: Status code is 200` alert.Surely is `request.status == 200` then the code shouldn't enter this `else` block?

Comment: @Michael, that's true in general but not in this example, because the extra line of code causes the parser to have already left the `if` clauses, leaving the `else` dangling (disconnected if we were to be precise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a bunch of braces, and on the `update_select()` line, it is causing a problem. The braces aren't strictly required for most of these blocks, but because you are attempting to execute two statements in the first `if()` you'll need them. Best to put them in everywhere.

```
function updatePage() {   
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        // Second statement executed after the if() 
        // MUST use {} on this block
        update_select($('select[name=island_name]'), data);
    }
    else if (request.status == 404) {
        alert("Request url does not exist");
    }
    else {
        alert("Error: status code is " + request.status);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Best advice: use them everywhere, it looks a little eyesore, but rather that than confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
function updatePage() {   
if (request.readyState == 4)
    if (request.status == 200)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        update_select($('select[name=island_name]'), data);
    }
    else if (request.status == 404)
        alert("Request url does not exist");
    else
        alert("Error: status code is " + request.status);
}
```

You indented line 5 (`update_select...`), but it was not really in the `if`.

Comment: You are still missing a curly bracket at line 2.

Comment: @Jules No, they are not needed.

Comment: @Jules The only one really needed to be syntactically correct is already in the place. Nothing wrong here...

Comment: @baruch I actually meant line 3. Either you edited your post or I didn't notice you placed your bracket on line 4. If it's the latter, then forget my remark.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the curly bracket { at line 2 and 3:

```
function updatePage() {   
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
      if (request.status == 200) {
          var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
          update_select($('select[name=island_name]'), data);
      }
      else if (request.status == 404)
         alert("Request url does not exist");
      else
        alert("Error: status code is " + request.status);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first set of braces you added is not strictly needed.

Comment: @baruch: Not strictly needed does not define a downvote. Not strictly needed braces do improve readability and avoid issues like Darwin Tech's in this case.

Comment: While I agree that doesn't deserve a downvote, you're being a little inconsistent here; you say they add readability and then you don't add them everywhere. That rule is then somewhat arbitrary, and the inconsistency is confusing for my taste.

Comment: @davin: I don't call it inconsistent, but I only leave out the brackets when there is just one line underneath as in the last 2 else cases. Different ways of working I guess.

Comment: @Jules I agree. I didn't downvote. I'll even +1 it for being the most readable solution.